# Django filter ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    # some fields
```

I want to filter Pages that belong to a particular category. For eg:

```
filtered_pages = Page.objects.filter(category1 in categories)
```

I think this should be simple in Django, but can't find a way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `categories` as a keyword argument:

```
filtered_pages = Page.objects.filter(categories=category1)
```

You can also use the category object's `page_set` to get related pages:

```
filtered_pages = category1.page_set.all()
```